# Exponential fit precision lost

Tags: fitting, physics, nonlinear, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I have a data:

```
data = {{1504., 0.38623}, {1698.56, 1.70795}, {1855.34, 4.77922}, {1998.22, 
  9.76965}, {1957.13, 7.34756}, {1924.72, 5.8017}, {1793.82, 
  2.84449}, {1679.68, 1.14792}, {1604.06, 0.765434}, {1422.63, 
  0.183902}, {1350.57, 0.078183}}
```

And I wanted to fit function

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, $\frac{c1}{Exp \left[\frac{c2 \left(\frac{3*10^8}{583.92*10^{-9}}\right)}{x+273.15}\right]-1}$, {c1, c2}, x]

I get warning: ...is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

How to fit this function?

Comment: Please include the actual code for `NonlinearModelFit` rather than the display format currently showing and decide if the data set is `data` or `data8`.

Comment: Given that `1/Exp[750.]` underflows, I'm not surprised, given the argument in your model. You might consider giving starting values, esp. for `c2`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The idea of starting values works.

Comment: Using anything between 10^-20 to 10^-10 as a starting value for `c2` works.  But it is simpler if you use `c1/(Exp[c0 /(x + 273.15)] - 1)` as the model and then solve for the appropriate multiple of `c0` to get `c2` because the default starting values work fine in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, there is simpliy a typo with `583.92 10^-9`  Get good result with positive exponent

```
model[x_] = c1/(Exp[(c2 ((3 10^8)/(583.92 10^9)))/(x + 273.15)] - 1)

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[x], {c1, c2}, x]

Normal[nlm]

(*   1.50253*10^6/(-1 + E^(27202./(273.15+ x)))   *)

Plot[Normal[nlm], {x, 1300, 2000}, Epilog -> Point@data]
```

Comment: The value `583.92 10^-9` is a wavelength in nanometers ($10^{-9}$ m)